# springmvc how to send multi dimensional radiobutton array to controller

Tags: spring-mvc, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a feedback from but i am not able to get any example on how to send multidimensional int array from form to controller.

**feedback from pic** : http://oi58.tinypic.com/p1z10.jpg

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitfeedback", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postsubmitfeedback(@ModelAttribute("answer") @RequestParam("email") String email,
        @RequestParam("feedback_id") Integer feedback_id, @RequestParam(value="myanswer[]") int [] myanswer,  Answer answer,
        Locale locale) {

        for(int i=0; i<myanswer.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(myanswer[i]);
        }
    return "submitfeedback";
}
```

**Jsp Form**

```
<form:form commandName="feedback">
<c:forEach items="${questionList}" var="question">
<c:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}"/>
<tr>
    <td>${counter}</td>
    <td>${question.question}</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="myanswer[${count}]" id="radio" value="1" /> 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="myanswer[${count}]" id="radio" value="2" /> 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="myanswer[${count}]" id="radio" value="3" /> 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="myanswer[${count}]" id="radio" value="4" /> 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="myanswer[${count}]" id="radio" value="5" /> 5</td>

</tr>
<c:set var="count" value="${count+1}"/>
</c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I strongly recommend you to encapsulate your parameters in an object.

```
class FeedbackForm {
   private String email;
   private Integer feedbackId;
   private Integer answer;
   /** Getters and setters. */
}
```

The html form inputs' names should match the field names.

Secondly, you have a radio button control, I doubt you will end up with an array of ints, since you can only have one radio button selected at all times. In the bean above, I've corrected it to a single answer. Radio buttons are a bit bizarre, since they're multiple inputs inside the form. you should probably have something like this :

```
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" onClick="changeMyHiddenField()" />1
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" onClick="changeMyHiddenField()" />2
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" onClick="changeMyHiddenField()" />3
<form {...}> <input id="myHiddenField" type="hidden" name="answer" /> </form>
```

Thirdly, You have no validation of the client's input. You should take advantage of Spring's bean validation.

```
@Min(value = 1, message = "Min is 1.")
@Max(value = 5, message = "Max is 5.")
private Integer answer;
```

Finally, your method signature should look like this:

```
public String postFeedback(@ModelAttribute @Valid FeedbackForm form, HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to implement validation later. I will keep your suggestions in mind. But how to get input from form to controller?

Comment: Spring maps it automatically using the method's ModelAttribute field names. Btw, you should NOT have validation only on the client side. This is a really bad code smell. Disabling javascript on your website will destroy your validation. You should have validation on both the client and on the server.

Comment: It maps it automatically using the beans' field name and the inputs' name. For instance, `­­­­<input id="myHiddenField" type="hidden" name="answer" />` will map directly to the  `FeedbackForm`'s `private Integer answer;`

Comment: Ok, as long as your data is validated along the wire.

Comment: Given solution is not working because i want to implement many radio-button groups in my form.